# Let object id within second table be unique

Tags: oracle, object, user-defined-types

I got the following sql:

```
create or replace type MEDIUM_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
me_movie REF MOVIE_TYPE,
me_rating varchar2(2),
me_runtime number(3,0),
me_release_year number(4,0),
me_list_price number(3,2),
me_our_price number(3,2),
me_availability varchar2(128),
me_aspect_ratio varchar2(8),
me_encoding number (1,0),
me_subtitle_language SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE_TYPE,
me_number_of_discs number (1,0)
)not final
/
create table DVD of MEDIUM_TYPE
object id system generated 
/
```

How can i make sure that me_movie in the dvd table is unique?

And also, how can i do something like this?

```
mo_release_year number(4,0) BETWEEN 1900 AND 2100,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same syntax as for relational tables:

```
create table DVD of MEDIUM_TYPE
   ( me_movie primary key )  
object id system generated 
/
```

The one problem you have is that you will run into this error:

```
ORA-02329: column of datatype REF cannot be unique or a primary key
```

Which admittedly is a bit of a showstopper.  You will need to re-think your whole model.  Sorry about that.